# React-native component for codemirror/highlight.js

Tags: react-native, codemirror, highlight.js

Is there a react-native viewer component for source code?
Looking for a component with support for different languages and themes like codemirror, highlight.js.

Thanks.

Comment: you can use - https://github.com/conorhastings/react-native-syntax-highlighter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment. Keep your eye out on https://github.com/jondot/awesome-react-native

Comment: Any suggestions for showing code blocks in the app?

Comment: you could just style it with a fixed-width font and a grey background color

Comment: 2018 and still not there